# How can I check mouse events as a background process in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, events, parallel-processing, mouse

I am using Matlab to develop an application which performs several mathematical operations, whose parameters can be changed when the mouse is clicked, as in the example below.

```
while time<endtime
 calculate_manythings;
if ~mod(time,checkmouse)
  mouseinput_timeout(timemouse, gca);
  change_calculation_parameters;
end
  time=time+1;
end
```

At the moment, I am pausing the operations periodically to check for mouse events, but this is slow and unpractical. How can I monitor these continually and run the code at the same time? Could I make the mouse event checks a background process using parfeval, for example?

Many thanks,
Marta

Answer (score 0):

you can use [callback functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/callback-definition.html). here I used `'ButtonDownFcn'`:

```
timeinterval = 1; % seconds between mouse clicks
% generate axes with callback function
h = plot(rand(1,2),'LineWidth',6);
set(gca,'ButtonDownFcn',@callback);
% reset Tag and time
h.Tag = '';
tic;
while true
    drawnow;
    if strcmp(h.Tag,'Pressed') % if pressed
        t = toc; % check time passed
        if t >= timeinterval
            % change parameters
            disp('Pressed');
            h.Color = rand(1,3);
            % reset timer
            tic;
        end
        % reset Tag
        h.Tag = '';
    end
end
```

and the callback function is:

```
function callback(src,~)
src.Children(1).Tag = 'Pressed';
end
```

Comment: I think that might help... So I can carry on doing my calculation and check whether the was pressed ever so often. Will the callback function recall more than one event, if the mouse was pressed more than once between checks? Thanks!